# Not Working - Multiple Machines Tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials, talker, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Tutorial:**

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

The following commands working on a local machine:

- `rosrun rospy_tutorails talker`
- `rosrun rospy_tutorials listener`

Talker output:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.541468] hello world 1457273968.54
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.645381] hello world 1457273968.65
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.746015] hello world 1457273968.75
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.844568] hello world 1457273968.84
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.945620] hello world 1457273968.95
```

Listener output:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.541901] /listener_8333_1457273959532I heard hello world 1457273968.54
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.645969] /listener_8333_1457273959532I heard hello world 1457273968.65
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.746562] /listener_8333_1457273959532I heard hello world 1457273968.75
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.845211] /listener_8333_1457273959532I heard hello world 1457273968.84
[INFO] [WallTime: 1457273968.946216] /listener_8333_1457273959532I heard hello world 1457273968.95
```

The location machine is OS X 10.11.3 and IP is 10.0.0.6
My remote machine is Ubuntu 14.04.5 and IP Is 10.0.0.4

SSH to both machines works. I the set `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.6"` and while the talker works, the listener does not hear any messages. How can I get this to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228363/not-working---multiple-machines-tutorial/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I the set `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.6"` and while the talker works, the listener does not hear any messages. How can I get this to work?

Just a guess, but probably by setting `ROS_MASTER_URI` to `http://10.0.0.6:11311` (note the port), and by either providing a working DNS (entry) for all the involved machines, or by setting `ROS_IP` to the correct values.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-07**:
Turns out I had set the remote to `http://localhost:11311` and had forgot to switch it back to `http:10.0.0.6:11311` - Your answer tipped me off to the issue.